# Is it posible to use Selenide with SRWare Iron Browser?

Tags: gradle

I try without success to start gradle task for testing the example from Selenide https://github.com/codeborne/selenide_examples .

The problem - I can only use IE or SRWare Iron. SRWare Iron based on Chromium and it should be possible, but how?

Answer (score 2):

The question is not Selenide related, but Selenium WebDriver related. 
The question is, can ChromeDriver drive "SRWare Iron" browser. I don't know.
Actually I believe you don't really "SRWare Iron" browser. The only difference from Chrome is that "SRWare Iron" doesn't track user actions and show flash. But it's not important when running tests. So, just run your tests with Chrome. It's simple.

Comment: :) The problem is that Chrome is banned in my current company :)

Comment: So if Chrome and Iron is basically the same, why won't ChromeDriver work with it?

Answer (score 1):

SRWare Iron - it is a Chrome clone.
So, you can make a trick:

1) Download SRWare Iron portabler (I did not checked is it possible with standard version);

2) rename file `IronPortable.exe` to  `Chrome.exe`

3) Download web driver for Chrome (I had used for Chrome 74): http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

4) Copy chromedriver.exe to the folder with Iron Portable;

5) Add folder Iron Portable's directory to PATH (https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/)

6) reboot PC;

7) use code for Chrome (Python):

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```